# Create terminal name for execute python script in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal

I have a python file in: '/home/username/scripts/pyscript' and I want set a word for execute directly this script.

I want do this "python3 /home/username/scripts/pyscript/main.py arg1 arg2" but looks like
this "myscript arg1 arg2"

Is this posible?
Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solver with the help of @pierpaciugo
I add a alias at the end of the .bashrc for make it persistent:

```
alias create='bash /home/username/Programming/Python/GithubAPI/script.sh'
```

I couldn't use only alias because I have my python dependencies on a virtual environment so if I try this i could not add params to my python script.

For that I create this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /home/username/Programming/Python/GithubAPI/venv/bin/activate && python3 /home/username/Programming/Python/GithubAPI/main.py $@ && deactivate
```

Now I can write "create param1 param2" and it works.
I am using all global paths but could be a good idea add the script in a folder in my PATH.

Answer (score 2):

It is possibile in a number of ways. Links are for [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), supposedly your shell but the ideas always apply.

First option: make a shell [alias](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html)

```
alias myscript='python3 /home/username/scripts/pyscript/main.py'
```

Be sure to add the alias to your .profile to make it survive logout.

Second option: define a [wrapper script](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/wrapper.html). Create a file with the following content, named after your desired command (e.g. myscript):

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 /home/username/scripts/pyscript/main.py "$@"
```

save it and make it executable, then call it :

```
chmod +x myscript
./myscript arg1 arg2
```

Be sure to copy the script in a folder in your PATH (check where with echo $PATH) to be able to call it from any folder.

Comment: I just discover alias, thank  you so much. Finally I made a merge between both methods, I am going to explain in another response.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`pyinstaller`](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) to create a single file executable:

**Step 1:** Install `pyinstaller`

<sub>[Note: best practice is to do this in a [`virutalenv`](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/)]</sub>

```sh
$ pip install pyinstaller
```

**Step 2:** Run `pyinstaller` against your script

```sh
$ pyinstaller --console --onefile /home/username/scripts/pyscript

$ pyinstaller pyscript.spec  # use this after the first run
```

**Step 3:** Test the generated executable

```sh
$ cd /home/username/scripts/dist  # generated by pyinstaller
$ pyscript arg1 arg2
```

**Step 4:** Leverage the $PATH variable

```sh
$ cp /home/username/scripts/dist/pyscript /usr/bin
```

You should now be able to run the executable from anywhere.

It should be noted that the executable that is generated is OS specific. For example, if you generate it on an Ubuntu machine, it will only run on Ubuntu (Debian based). The same holds true for Windows and other Linux distros.